# Displaying data from a class

Tags: c#

So, I have a card.  This classes constructors are as follows:

```
public Cards(int data, string typeIEking, string suitIEspades)
{
    valueOfCard = data;
    specialCards = typeIEking;
    suit = suitIEspades;
}

public Cards(int data, string suitIEspades)
{
    valueOfCard = data;
    specialCards = null;
    suit = suitIEspades;
}
```

I have previously put data in this card but now and I want to display the data (named valueOfCard in the constructor), suit and if it's a special card (i.e. a king).

So I pass this card into another method but now I want to display the data in the result but when I type cardName the only options that come up is `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`.

I'm confused to why this is happening and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
I'd imagined I'd just do `nameOfCard.valueOfCard;`

Comment: Are `valueOfCard`, `specialCards` and `suit` all `private` fields? They'll need to be `public` properties in order to access them outside of the class itself.

Comment: show us the `another method`

Comment: Please comment so I can say your answer solved it :D. Thank you v much.. I completely overlooked that.. I owe you one man @DaveZych

Comment: @user3245390 np. done!

Comment: @user3245390 You should accept the answer instead of adding "[solved]" in question title.

Comment: Read above lol, their is a time limit which is why I told dave (above) to comment so i mark it as answered. @timrau

Comment: @user3245390 when you finish working on your program, you might be interested in visiting http://codereview.stackexchange.com and ask for suggestions on how to improve it, or sections of it.

Comment: @ANeves I will do thanks, I'll put that on my favourites :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `valueOfCard`, `specialCards` and `suit` all `private` fields instead of `public` properties. Update them to be `public` and you should be able to access them outside of the class.

If you don't specify any access modifier, the field/property is `private` by default.

Comment: The answer would be improved if it mentioned that fields and properties are `private` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your member variables are private fields so they won't appear outside your class. You need to provide some public properties for the private fields in your Cards class.

Something like:

```
private int valueOfCard;
public int ValueOfCard 
{ 
   get { return valueofCard; } 
   private set { valueOfCard = value; } 
}
```

or you could turn them into auto-properties

```
public int ValueOfCar { get; set; }
```

(NB the name case change, not essential but a good style to adopt)

Comment: What are auto properties? How do they differ from the first one you provided?

Comment: @user3245390 for auto properties, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**Problem:** I Suspect that you have not declared `properties` for your variables or you have not used `public` access modifier for your variables(it is not recommended).

**Solution :** I would suggest to create `properties` for your variables to access them outside the class.

Try This:

```
class MyClass
{

    public int valueOfCard{get;set;}
    public string specialCards{get;set;}
    public string suit{get;set;}

    //here your constructors.
    public Cards(int data, string typeIEking, string suitIEspades)
    {
        valueOfCard = data;
        specialCards = typeIEking;
        suit = suitIEspades;
    }

    public Cards(int data, string suitIEspades)
    {
        valueOfCard = data;
        specialCards = null;
        suit = suitIEspades;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't right, there's no connection between the public and private members here (valueofCard and ValueOfCard).

Comment: agreed.... my point exactly ;-) but what happens to the value of valueOfCard if I set ValueOfCard. I'm not 100% sure of the requirement here, but I'm pretty sure the OP will want them to be the same value.